# mysql service as type: ExternalName is not able to conenct from other namespace in Kubernetes ( minikube )

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, service, minikube

I have a mysql service deployed in namespace : **mysqlns**. Following is the service defination.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: mysqlns
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    name: tcp
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  type: ClusterIP
```

Now I do have a spring boot application deployed in **default** namespace

That service defination is as below

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: opapolicystoreapp-t1
  labels:
    app: opapolicystoreapp-t1
    service: opapolicystoreapp-t1
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8484
    name: http
  selector:
    app: opapolicystoreapp-t1
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: mysql.mysqlns.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
  - port: 3306
---
```

Mysql service in mysqlns is deployed properly and running

but when I am trying to deploy my application in default namespace .. service type ExternalName never came up .. and it is not running, hence my application is also not able to connect to mysql external service.

I am using springboot application property file to connect to service

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://mysql/policyds 
        username: xxxx 
        password: XXXX
```

Not able to find the mistake here.

Comment: appliation is throwing following error : Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql

Comment: why not use mysql.mysqlns.svc.cluster.local in the spring boot app and avoid creating another service

Comment: Let me give it a try

Comment: Nope, it didn't work .. url: jdbc:mysql://mysql.mysqlns.svc.cluster.local/policyds it will not work because services are on different namespace .. ExternalName should be the solution ..but not able to understand why it is not working

Comment: ExternalName is for connecting to services outside kubernetes. what is the error you get and share output of kubectl describe svc mysql

Comment: I think we can connect to service to other namespace also .. that is the way out .. let me share a document with you .. https://8gwifi.org/docs/kube-externalname.jsp

Comment: what error you get ? and share output of kubectl describe svc mysql -n mysqlns

Comment: If you dig a bit you can find out that ExternalName type of service is nothing but CNAME. So if you can't connect to mysql using in-cluster FQDN then its not going to work.

Comment: can you paste content of `/etc/resolv.conf` file from your application container?

Comment: root@opapolicystoreapp-t1-798cd97c57-qnf7f:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5

Comment: Is there any concept that core dns does not support ExternalName. only kube-dns support it

Comment: `"Is there any concept that core dns does not support ExternalName"` - I have tried it on coreDNS and it works just fine. /etc/resolv.conf file also looks fine. Try running dig container and try to resolv the domain with `dig +search mysql.mysqlns` and see if it works because maybe the problem is not with dns but with the application itself